# XML Append in c#

Tags: c#, xml

```
XmlElement x = xmlDoc.CreateElement("place");
x.InnerText = 1;
root.AppendChild(x);
x.InnerText = 2;
```

is the value of “place” in the XML 1 or 2?

Comment: should be pretty easy to try yourself?

Comment: the variable x is an object and the object does not change if you add it to another object.  So the answer is 2.

Answer (score 0):

it came down to whatever the last value was before the save.